# Vue.js + Element UI: Split row on two rows

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

I've a simple [el-table](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table) with many columns (ten exactly).
So, some column is too narrow for its content. I'd like to split each row in two rows, is it possible?

Something like:

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| ROW1 | ROW1 | ROW1 |
|      | ROW1 | ROW1 |
| ROW2 | ROW2 | ROW2 |
|      | ROW2 | ROW2 |
| ROW3 | ROW3 | ROW3 |
|      | ROW3 | ROW3 |
```

I tried with something like the following with no success:

```
<el-table :data="myData" stripe="stripe">
  <el-row>
    <el-table-column prop="position" label="Col1">...</el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="position" label="Col2">...</el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="position" label="Col3">...</el-table-column>
  </el-row>
  <el-row>
    <el-table-column prop="position" label="Col4">...</el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="position" label="Col5">...</el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="position" label="Col6">...</el-table-column>
  </el-row>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm it seems its not possible using markup but it seems its possible using code. you need to bind `span-method` attribute for it.

```
<el-table
      :data="tableData6"
      :span-method="spanLogicMethod"
      border
      style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px">
```

and add method to your parent instance you can add this `spanMethod` method. inside you will get current `column` , `row` and its index so based on that you can return `span` values.

for more information you can check `Rowspan and colspan` in docu 
http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        // some data
      }  
    },
    methods: {
      spanLogicMethod({ row, column, rowIndex, columnIndex }) {
        if (columnIndex === 0) {
          if (rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
            return {
              rowspan: 2,
              colspan: 1
            };
          } else {
            return {
              rowspan: 0,
              colspan: 0
            };
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```